# String.Format trivial alignment issue

Tags: c#

It looks like a trivial alignment issue. As I understand (-) in the String.Format is used for left-handed and (+) for right-handed alignment.
The output with the following code looks strange. Several data from line 4 are shifted in between. Maybe, some of you have an idea .. many thanks.

```
string format = "{0,-15:0}{1,15:#,##0.00}{2,15:#,##0.00}";

for (int i = 0; i < monthCount; i++)
{                 
    string output = String.Format(format,
    i,
    arrDouble1[i], 
    arrDouble2[i]);
    textBox1.Text += output +"\r\n";
}

Output in windows form ..
1                   121.205,63     180.000,00
2                   242.258,26     218.000,00
3                   265.330,48     261.000,00
4                   242.258,26         0,00
5                   57.894,74           0,00
6                   57.894,74           0,00
7                   55.263,16           0,00
8                   57.894,74           0,00
```

Comment: "shifted in between", can you please explain what you mean here?

Comment: Have you ensured you are using a monospace font on the textbox?

Comment: What Windows component ist used for display?

Comment: Can you please post the actual code? you're looping from 0 yet the first line has 1 in the first column.

Comment: Why aren't you using a component more suited to grid-like data, like oh, I don't know, a grid?

Comment: Works perfectly fine to me, using a monospaced font ( http://s13.postimg.org/7yi0sg8ef/screenshot_27.png )

Comment: Your code works fine. Problem could be with font that your component using like @LasseV.Karlsen said.

Comment: Lasse, you are right. It's simply about using a "monospace font" such as courier instead of sans serif i used before. many thanks ..